# Make animation to pseudo classes by CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, click, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname

I made [a set of social button on Codepen](http://codepen.io/chenghuayang/pen/zvjpBG) which is used to share things. But I met some CSS or Javascript problem. I'd like to get the `.sharer::before`, which is diamond-shaped and the colored background of each button, move to the top after a click event.

[image: Normal state for button]

Normal state for button (The little triangle is the corner of the diamond background)

[image: Hover state]

In hover state, the button is filled with the whole diamond background.

[image: After clicking the button]

After clicking the button, the diamond background would fly to the top.

I made a `.success` class name to have the successful states after clicking the button, but this block of Javascript seems wrong. All I want is to add `.success` to the `.sharer` which is clicked already. ([Codepen](http://codepen.io/chenghuayang/pen/zvjpBG))

```js
function addSuccess(currentClass) { 
 document.getElementsByClassName(currentClass).classList.add("success");
}

document.getElementsByClassName("sharer").addEventListener("click", addSuccess("sharer"), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with `getElementsByClassName` that returns an **array** of elements, whereas `addEventListener` should be called on a **single** element.

If you were using a helper library like jQuery, you could have done something like this without having to worry about how many elements you manipulate.

For vanilla elements like in your case, you should iterate over the array of elements.

Another issue is in your `addSuccess` function: how do you select the specific element you want to apply your new class `success` to? As-is (after adding the iteration though), it would blindly apply the new class to every element.

Finally, the `addEventListener` takes a function as 2nd argument, not an expression (like your function with an argument). It would have worked if calling `addSuccess("sharer")` had returned a function.

The resulting code:

```js
function addSuccess(event) { 
    var clickedButton = event.target;
    clickedButton.classList.add("success");
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("sharer");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", addSuccess, false);
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPeLRp

Note that you are also missing a CSS rule to stick your diamond to the top once the `success` class is added. As-is, your diamond goes to the top only on hover.

The missing rule:

```css
.sharer.success::before {
    top: -208%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Got some questions. Is `event.target` somewhat the same as `return`? And, why it is `addSuccess`(inside addEventListener), not `addSuccess(buttons[i])`?

Comment: Google is your primary source of information: [event.target](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+event+target) and [addEventListener](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+addeventlistener). Or simply [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) as nicely suggested by @Sergey Kopyrin

Comment: Thanks. I've googled it, but not sured. (I'm new to JS. :D) Does `addSuccess` with `event.target` mean to take action, and `addSuccess(sth)` mean to return an object back? So the latter one didn't work in `addEventListener`?

Comment: Forget about the `event.target` for now. The `addEventListener` expects a **function** as 2nd argument. You can give this function either by 1) simply giving its identifier (name) - without anything else (that is my solution), 2) by providing an expression (like `myFunction(someArguments)`) that will be executed right now, but it must return a *function*, or 3) by declaring an anonymous function, like Sergey did in `Array.prototype.forEach.call`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I appreciate that very much! :D Could you please give me example about the first method? I'm very interested in the use of it! :)

Comment: The "first method" is the one I use in my above code: declare a function somewhere with an identifier (`addSucess`, as you did also), then provide just that identifier as the 2nd argument of `addEventListener`. When the event happens, `addEventListener` will call that function and give it an `event` as only argument, as explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Add_a_simple_listener).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this:

```
var shares = document.getElementsByClassName("sharer");

function addSuccess() {
  this.classList.add('success');
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(shares, function(share) {
  share.addEventListener('click', addSuccess);
});
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that it takes **all** elements with className 'share' and is trying to add event listener to HTMLCollection itself. What you need is to add this event listener to **every** element. You can do this by `forEach` method, but this is the method of Array object, and due to this you have to use `Array.prototype.forEach.call(shares, fn)`- this allows you to use Array methods on HTMLCollection.

In provided `fn` you pass every single element as argument (function(**share**)), to which you add your event listener. In the function in event listener you have access to *this* - it is an element, to which you added event.

For better understanding, that can be not provided by my answer, you can look [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org).

Comment: Thanks! Is `Array` needed to be specified?

Comment: `Array.prototype` is needed, because it has method `forEach`. You can also get this method from created array, like this: `[].forEach.call(...)`.

Comment: Or you can use `Array.from(HTMLCollection)` from ES2015 to create array from your HTMLColletction and use it with all array methods you need :) But for this you need [BabelJs](https://babeljs.io).